# How can I decode the event log I receive in my txn where there more than 1 smart contract involved and the emitted event cannot be found in ABI

Tags: events, polygon, proxy-contracts, protocol

I'm trying to build a dapp using the [lens protocol](https://docs.lens.dev/docs/testnet-addresses) and I'm struggling to find the right way to decode the event logs.

Scenario:
I'm trying to publish the post using the POST method in the proxy contract [LensHub Proxy](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0xF6BF84E5df229029C9D36dC7ABaCDBE9c0bd7b4F). with some insights from a person in the lenshub community I was told that I should use the proxy contract for all txns and use the ABI [LensHUb Implementation](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0x4F0c856b2FA2c1e0E1AC971B462FCCF4654E8045) with it. Therefore as you can see in the below code I have used to do the implementation as the community guidelines.

```
const contractAddress = "0xf6bf84e5df229029c9d36dc7abacdbe9c0bd7b4f"; // Lenshub Proxy
const proxyLensHubAbi = abi; // abi of implementation
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
  "https://polygon-mumbai.g.alchemy.com/v2/key"
);
const contract = new ethers.Contract(
  contractAddress,
  proxyLensHubAbi,
  provider
);
const signer = new ethers.Wallet(
  "key",
  provider
);
const inputStruct = {
  profileId: 169189,
  contentURI:
    "https://ipfs.fleek.co/ipfs/plantghostplantghostplantghostplant",
  collectModule: "0xedeb556d916d9e6e154a083ac18da52cc5ed8b1c",
  collectModuleData: [],
  referenceModule: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  referenceModuleData: [],
};
const signedContract = await contract.connect(signer);
const result = await signedContract.post(inputStruct);
const receipt = await result.wait();
console.log(receipt.events, "events");
console.log("result", receipt);
```

The problem:

The problem I'm facing here is with the event emitted with this txn. The "Post created" event is emitted where the pubID and other post-related details are returned but because the data returned are all hex I need to decode them. but when decoding what I get is an empty array. What I'm guessing is the event emitted cannot be found in the contracts abi so, therefore, using the abi for decoding is not working. Is this the reason or am I doing anything working? How can I do this?

I'm Just stuck

The code for decoding

```
const publishingLogicAbi = publishing;
abiDecoder.addABI(publishingLogicAbi);
const decodedLogs = abiDecoder.decodeLogs(receipt.events);
console.log(decodedLogs);
```

This is a simulation I did using Tenderly
https://dashboard.tenderly.co/h_rrishs_work/project/simulator/2ed296f1-8235-4b68-a41f-662fc7ef1f94

[image: smart contracts in tenderly]

As you can see there are three contracts participating in this contract.

[image: events]

The topic data is decoded and shown here. The blockchain used here is the Mumbai testnet

Comment: The tenderly link requires a login, so it isn't that useful.

Answer (score 3):

The ABI posted to Mumbai implementation contract is probably lacking.

Take transaction `0x32e3230a7478315092a04ef57fc2426947ec5031c6977c7b184e7bcd02be9216` for instance, if you look at [Mumbai Explorer](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x32e3230a7478315092a04ef57fc2426947ec5031c6977c7b184e7bcd02be9216#eventlog) that calls the same method `0x963ff141` (post), under logs you'll see log #159 which is submitted by contract `0xf6bf84e5df229029c9d36dc7abacdbe9c0bd7b4f` (the proxy) - the first topic `0xc672c38b4d26c3c978228e99164105280410b144af24dd3ed8e4f9d211d96a50` is the event emitted.

If you look at the encoded implementation ABI, there's no method with signature matching to this topic, that's why you're not getting anything.

To back this up, looking at the implementation source code, you can see that `post(...)` calls `PublishingLogic.createPost(...)` which in turn emits an event `PostCreated` - this event is missing from the ABI.

If you add the missing `PostCreated` event to the ABI manually -

```
{
    "anonymous": false,
    "inputs": [
        { "indexed": true, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "profileId", "type": "uint256" },
        { "indexed": true, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "pubId", "type": "uint256" },
        { "indexed": false, "internalType": "string", "name": "contentURI", "type": "string" },
        { "indexed": false, "internalType": "address", "name": "collectModule", "type": "address" },
        { "indexed": false, "internalType": "bytes", "name": "collectModuleReturnData", "type": "bytes" },
        { "indexed": false, "internalType": "address", "name": "referenceModule", "type": "address" },
        { "indexed": false, "internalType": "bytes", "name": "referenceModuleReturnData", "type": "bytes" },
        { "indexed": false, "internalType": "uint256", "name": "timestamp", "type": "uint256" }
    ],
    "name": "PostCreated",
    "type": "event"
}
```

decoding will manage to produce a result -

```
[{"name":"PostCreated","events":[{"name":"profileId","type":"uint256","value":"129"},{"name":"pubId","type":"uint256","value":"26"},{"name":"contentURI","type":"string","value":"https://theagora.vercel.app/posts/6260ca6331de6ff150e48df2"},{"name":"collectModule","type":"address","value":"0xedeb556d916d9e6e154a083ac18da52cc5ed8b1c"},{"name":"collectModuleReturnData","type":"bytes","value":null},{"name":"referenceModule","type":"address","value":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"},{"name":"referenceModuleReturnData","type":"bytes","value":null},{"name":"timestamp","type":"uint256","value":"1650510457"}],"address":"0xF6BF84E5df229029C9D36dC7ABaCDBE9c0bd7b4F"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You get empty array because in your abi missing the events abi.

Try this:

```
const abi = [
    {
        "anonymous": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "profileId",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "indexed": true,
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "pubId",
                "type": "uint256"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "internalType": "string",
                "name": "contentURI",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "collectModule",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "internalType": "bytes",
                "name": "collectModuleReturnData",
                "type": "bytes"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "internalType": "address",
                "name": "referenceModule",
                "type": "address"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "internalType": "bytes",
                "name": "referenceModuleReturnData",
                "type": "bytes"
            },
            {
                "indexed": false,
                "internalType": "uint256",
                "name": "timestamp",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],

        name: "PostCreated",
        type: "event",
    }
]
let txrecepit = await provider.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txhash);
abiDecoder.addABI(abi);
var log = abiDecoder.decodeLogs(txrecepit.logs);
console.log(log[0].events);
```

Response :

```
[
  { name: 'profileId', type: 'uint256', value: '129' },
  { name: 'pubId', type: 'uint256', value: '24' },
  {
    name: 'contentURI',
    type: 'string',
    value: 'https://theagora.vercel.app/posts/625775f875f4fe66b1e4c53a'
  },
  {
    name: 'collectModule',
    type: 'address',
    value: '0xedeb556d916d9e6e154a083ac18da52cc5ed8b1c'
  },
  { name: 'collectModuleReturnData', type: 'bytes', value: null },
  {
    name: 'referenceModule',
    type: 'address',
    value: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
  },
  { name: 'referenceModuleReturnData', type: 'bytes', value: null },
  { name: 'timestamp', type: 'uint256', value: '1649904205' }
]
```

Comment: You just copied my answer...